# WCF Services not working from Silverlight Application after Deploying

Tags: wcf, silverlight-4.0

Okay I have seen some very similar questions here but none seem to be answered to my liking.  I have created a Silverlight application that calls a couple of services to populate various comboboxes from the database.  I got this working without too much trouble on my local machine.

So now I want to deploy it to our webserver.  It was relatively straight forward to get ISS7 to load the Silverlight application.  However, none of my services seem to be working properly, in that the comboboxes are empty.  In IE I get the following error:

> Message: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application An exception occurred during the operation, making the result invalid.  Check InnerException for exception details.   at System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs.RaiseExceptionIfNecessary()
>      at MyTestPage.ViewModel.MyService.GetInfoCompletedEventArgs.get_Result()
>      at MyTestPage.ViewModel.MainPageViewModel.b__2(Object s, GetInfoCompletedEventArgs ea)
>      at MyTestPage.ViewModel.MyService.MyServiceClient.OnGetInfoCompleted(Object state)
>   Line: 1
>   Char: 1
>   Code: 0
>   URI: http://www.mywebsite.com/MyTestPage.aspx

My problem is that this error only occurs when deploying on the webserver and I have no clue how to debug this problem.  The error says to check the InnerException but I haven't found an answer yet (after hours of searching) that tells me how I should do this.

I have tried browsing to the services and I am able to do so using the domain name i.e. http://test.myserver.com/Services/MyService.svc.  However when logged onto the server and using http://localhost:3456/Services/MyService.svc - which is the path in the ServicesReferences.ClientConfig file - It cannot be found.

Some answers here seem to suggest using a clientaccesspolicy.xml file but I don't understand why this should be necessary if the services are hosted on the same server as the application - they aren't required when debugging on my local machine.  Despite my reservations I have tried adding a clientaccesspolicy.xml file to the root of the application but this still doesn't make any difference.

So I have a couple of questions:

1) How do I get access to the InnerException when I am running the application on the webserver?  Is there a specific log file I can view or turn on?

2) If, for some reason, I am trying to access the service in a cross domain fashion (even though they are located on the same server) how do I configure the application so that this isn't required?

UPDATE:

Ok, I was able to get the tracing to work.  I can now see the trace details on the page when it loads but it doesn't really tell me anything useful.  I have also added the option to write the details to the disk.  Initially this file wasn't being written and I couldn't understand why.  Then I noticed that refreshing my silverlight application was not triggering a write to the log.  It was only when I manually browsed to the services that the log file was updated.  This seems to indicate to me that my silverlight application is not hitting the services at all (for some reason).  I tried cutting out the View Model object and hitting the service directly from the xaml code behind file but this didn't make any difference either.

At this point after spending more than two days trying to figure this out, I am thinking about starting again from scratch.

For my mind it shouldn't be this difficult to deploy something that works on a development machine to a webserver.

Comment: Do you installed the WCF Ria Services on the webserver?

Comment: Yes I have installed the RIA Services on the webserver using the SERVER=true option.  I think it must be something to do with the fact that I can access the service using the domain name but I am unable to reach the service when trying to browse to it on localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I pretty much gave up on my initial approach.  I had another go following along from this video http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/all/net-ria-services-intro/.  It uses Domain services instead of the WCF Services and it was actually fairly straight forward to get it going on the webserver.  The example is two years old now so maybe there are better ways to do this now (I am open to suggestions) but at least it worked within an hour of trying it (compared to 2.5 days and getting nowhere).

Comment: A DomainService is a WCF RIA Service. I think in your initial approach you used normal WCF Services. Take a look at this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707344%28v=VS.91%29.aspx to get more information about WCF RIA Services.

Comment: Yes, that's possible.  I find the terminologies used in the examples confusing at times.  It also doesn't help that a lot of examples out there all seem to do the same thing in different ways.  So it's hard for me to get a feel for what is the "right" or best way to something with Silverlight.

Comment: I´m using WCF RIA Services with Silverlight and for me it´s now very easy to develop and extend my system. The good thing about WCF RIA Services is that the client code to access the services is autogenerated, so you can use it right away.